# How to setup Webpack so that will be able to use Pug in both Single File Components (.vue) and "vue-class-component" classes?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack, vue-class-components

According Vue.js [documentatin](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html#typescript) to use pug pre-processor in Single File Components, [pug-plain-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pug-plain-loader) (**not** [pug-loader](https://github.com/pugjs/pug-loader)) required:

```
{
  test: /\.pug$/,
  loader: 'pug-plain-loader'
}
```

What if *besides* Singe File Components (.vue files) I also need to import pug templates to TypeScript classes, provided by [vue-property-decorator](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator) package (based on [vue-class-component](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component))?

I have to see the [example](https://qiita.com/hako1912/items/8d9968d07748d20825f8#%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%9D%E3%83%BC%E3%83%8D%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%81%AE%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%82%92%E3%81%A4%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8B) only for html template loading:

```js
@Component({
  template: require('./MyComponent.html')
})
export default class MyComponent extends Vue {
    //...
}
```

What if need to use pug instead?

```js
@Component({
  template: require('./RegularButton.pug')
})
export default class RegularButton extends Vue {
    //...
}
```

In this case, pug-plain-loader should not be used:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> <button @click="onClickEventHandler">{{ lettering }}</button>
 @ ../ReusableComponents/RegularButton/RegularButton.ts 18:18-48
 @ ./SPA_Test.ts
```

I know that first I need to install pug-loader. But how I need to harmonize my webpack config with pug-plain-loader settings?

```
// ...
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.ts?$/,
      loader: 'ts-loader',
      options: {
        appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/]
      }
    },
    {
      test: /\.json5$/,
      loader: 'json5-loader'
    },
    {
      test: /\.(yml|yaml)$/,
      use: ['json-loader', 'yaml-loader']
    },
    {
      test: /\.vue$/,
      loader: 'vue-loader'
    },
    {
      test: /\.pug$/,
      loader: 'pug-plain-loader'
    }
  ]
}
```

---

### Update: error output after first solution

```
NonErrorEmittedError: (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) 

  Errors compiling template:

  text "export default "" outside root element will be ignored.

  1  |  export default "<div class=\"container\"><h1>{{ pageTitle }}</h1><hr><div><div>V-Model Test：</div><div>{{ vModelTestProperty }}</div><div><input type=\"text\" v-model=\"vModelTestProperty\"></div></div><hr><div><div>{{ defaultTextLabel }}</div><div><RegularButton :lettering=\"&quot;Non default button text&quot;\" :onClickEventHandler=\"executeTest\"></RegularButton></div></div></div>"
     |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    at Object.emitError (C:\Users\i\Documents\PhpStorm\InHouseDevelopment\mylib\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:165:14)
    at Object.module.exports (C:\Users\i\Documents\PhpStorm\InHouseDevelopment\mylib\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\loaders\templateLoader.js:61:21)
 @ ./SPA_Test.vue?vue&type=template&id=cabf1cca&lang=pug& 1:0-422 1:0-422
 @ ./SPA_Test.vue
 @ ./SPA_Test.ts
```

Component:

```
<template lang="pug">
  .container

    h1 {{ pageTitle }}
    hr

    div
      div V-Model Test：
      div {{ vModelTestProperty }}
      div: input(type='text' v-model='vModelTestProperty')
    hr

    div
      div {{ defaultTextLabel }}
      div: RegularButton(:lettering='"Non default button text"' :onClickEventHandler='executeTest')
</template>


<script lang="ts">

  import { Vue, Component, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator'

  @Component
  export default class SPA_Test extends Vue {

    private pageTitle: string = 'SPA related test';
    private vModelTestProperty: string = 'Inputted characters will be displayed here';
    private defaultTextLabel: string = 'Default text';

    public executeTest(): void {
      console.log('Test O\'K');
    }
  }
</script>
```

I don't thing that @Hammerbot's solution is wrong; maybe it is a *part of right solution*. Anyway, with settings

```
{
  test: /\.vue$/,
  loader: 'vue-loader'
},
{
  test: /\.pug$/,
  loader: 'pug-plain-loader'
}
```

all works, unless `.pug` could not be imported inside `@Component` decorator:

```
import { Vue, Component, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component({
  //template: require('./RegularButton.pug') // error will occur
  template: '<button @click="onClickEventHandler">{{ lettering }}</button>'
})
export default class RegularButton extends Vue {

  @Prop({default: 'Default text', type: String}) private readonly lettering!: string;
  @Prop({default: (): void => {}, type: Function}) private readonly onClickEventHandler!: () => {};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to Vue.js official [documentation](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html#pug), to use `vue-loader` with `pug-plain-loader`, you need to configure loader rule as follows:

> If you also intend to use it to import `.pug` files as HTML strings in JavaScript, you will need to chain `raw-loader` after the preprocessing loader. Note however adding `raw-loader` would break the usage in Vue components, so you need to have two rules, one of them targeting Vue files using a `resourceQuery`, the other one (fallback) targeting JavaScript imports:
>
> ```
> // webpack.config.js -> module.rules
> {
>   test: /\.pug$/,
>   oneOf: [
>     // this applies to `<template lang="pug">` in Vue components
>     {
>       resourceQuery: /^\?vue/,
>       use: ['pug-plain-loader']
>     },
>     // this applies to pug imports inside JavaScript
>     {
>       use: ['raw-loader', 'pug-plain-loader']
>     }
>   ]
> }
> ```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Unfortunately, it did not work for me. Please, check the update in answer area.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu You might want to take a look at this: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html#pug. The vuejs official doc say slightly different from pug-plain-loader's doc.

Answer (score 1):

The working solution is:

```
{
    test: /\.pug$/,
    oneOf: [{
        resourceQuery: /^\?vue/,
        use: ["pug-plain-loader"]
    }, {
        use: [
            "html-loader",
            "pug-html-loader"
        ]
    }]
}
```